# Sharing a map across multiple java classes in multi thread environment

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a map of socket objects with socket connection prams as key.
When request comes to a service class to get socket with a key, i am fetching the connected socket object from map and requesting time from socket server to ensure the connection is OK. If the socket connection is dropped or got some exception am removing the object in a **call back method(which is in another class)**. My concern is i have to share the map of objects in different classes and then i have to do get(), put(), remove() in different classes.
I used synchronized HashMap and shared that in different classes as mentioned above.

```
public class ConnectionRegistry {
  private static Object lock = new Object();
  protected static final Map<ConnectionDetails, Connection> connectionMap = Collections
                .synchronizedMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<>());

    public ConnectionWrapper getWrapper(ConnectionDetails info){
      synchronized (lock) {
         Connection lsConnection = connectionMap.get(info);
          if (lsConnection == null) {
            // try to connect here to the socket server.
            // Will get the response connected then put it in the map 
          }
     }

      if(lsConnection != null){
          // request server time.
          return //socket object
      }else
          // null

    // This will get in different class and then try to update or delete object from map.     
    public static Map<ConnectionDetails, Connection> getConnectionMap() {
        return connectionMap;
    }
  }
```

Problem is when i get multiple threads with same connection details or different connection details threads are blocking.
How can i improve or share the map without blocking the thread with different connection details.

Comment: Why you are passing the concurrentHashMap which is threadsafe by default into Collections. SynchronizedMap()?... You are simply making the synchronized map again synchronized.

Comment: Am am going to change concurrentHashMap  to HashMap. Any how how can i stop blocking the threads.

Comment: I would suggest you to use concurrentHashMap here instead of making a HashMap synchronized. Because concurrentHashMap performs well when you have higher readers and fewer writers. And it uses multitude of locks, each lock controls one segment of the hash. This means two updates can simultaneously execute safely if they each affect separate buckets.